# Create a child process which cannot access any files a level above with Node.JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, permissions, file-management

I'm trying to develop a Node.JS Application that allows for users to create their own Node Apps which run as child processes to the main Node.JS app. The issue that I am having is that I do not know how to only give the corresponding child process permission to access and execute files inside it's own folder, eg. I don't want a child process to be able to see the files of another user.

I thought that I may be able to run a child process inside it's own folder, and only allow access to this folder from the enclosed files and the main Node.JS app (parent).

I have no clue as to how I may be able to do this, but I thought that I may be able to do this by using chmod, but I don't know exactly how this works, and I'm not sure how I would be able to only allow access from the parent process and enclosing files, and not from anywhere else?

I have enclosed a diagram of how I would like the data-flow to occur, incase I haven't explained properly:

[image]

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've mentioned `chmod` in your question, so I assume you're using a *nix-like operating system.

You can use a [`chroot` jail](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105/chroot-jail-what-is-it-and-how-do-i-use-it) for this. There's an npm module, [`chroot`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chroot), which can help. Here's an example from their docs:

> Bind a TCP server to a privileged port before dropping privileges.
>
> ```
> var net = require('net');
> var chroot = require('chroot');
>
> var server = net.createServer();
> server.listen(80, function(err) {
>   if (err) { throw err; }
>
>   try {
>     chroot('/var/empty', 'nobody');
>     console.log('changed root to "/var/empty" and user to "nobody"');
>   } catch(err) {
>     console.error('changing root or user failed', err);
>     process.exit(1);
>   }
> });
> ```

The first argument is the location that should be seen as "root" by the child process.

Comment: Note from the docs: the process must be started as the super user